# Thai Transit Visa For Sri Lankan Passport

Tags: visas, thailand, uk-residents, sri-lankan-citizens

I have a British passport, and my wife has a Sri Lankan passport with a permanent residence in the UK. We are going to Sri Lanka, with a 7 hour stopover in Bangkok. We are thinking of going out of the airport for a few hours. Does my wife need a transit visa? If she needs it, can I get it in time?

Answer (score 1):

Sri Lankan citizens [can not leave the airport and enter Thailand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Thailand) without obtaining a visa in advance. You can [apply for a Thai visa online](https://thaievisa.go.th/Home/). The website [advises](https://thaievisa.go.th/Home/TourismLeisure) applying for this visa fifteen days in advance. You should expect to pay [£60 for a single-entry visa](https://london.thaiembassy.org/en/publicservice/84398-visa-fee?page=5d6636cd15e39c3bd00072dd&menu=5f4b6eb3f6ae4b236972c562).